# Full screen in Safari

Tags: mobile-safari, fullscreen, pixi.js

I am developing a H5 Canvas game using PIXI js.
I am struggling in implementing the ios Safari swipe up to full screen message.

Added a new div with window.width + 1000 px.
It does remove the safari address bars but i am not sure when to remove the div. i.e. i am not able to identify if i am in full mode or not.
Also, what should i do to get back the div enabled if someone accidentally or forcefully comes out of full screen mode?

I am open to use any opensource lib as well but wasn't able to find one except **screenfull.js** which doesn't supports safari mobile